# Mongo text search does not seem to use the initial condition to reduce the number of documents to search

Tags: mongodb, search

I have a collection with text search enabled and and index of the FName column. If I perform a search like this:
`db.items.find({ "FName" : /^customer\\rainfall\\geometry\ types\\customer\ 1\ manhole\ monitors\\region\ 10\\area\ 100\\catchment\ 1000\\/ }).count()`

Then this is very fast and returns a value of 300 as there are 300 matching documents.

If, however, I run this query:

`db.items.find([{ "FName" : /^customer\\rainfall\\geometry\ types\\customer\ 1\ manhole\ monitors\\region\ 10\\area\ 100\\catchment\ 1000\\/ }, "$text" : { "$search" : "\"\\average rainfall\"" }]).count()`, it can take up to 20 seconds to complete. If I run the initial query, get all the documents and carry out the search client side it is much faster - a second or two.

How can this be faster given that the second query is actually being run on the database? It almost looks like the FName filter is not being used first but I cannot prove this.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Ian

Comment: https://p-mongo.github.io/mongodb-faq/query/indexing-query-optimization/#query-plan

Comment: The text index is always used first.